# getLastknownLocation() returns null value on nexus

Tags: android, location

i am developing location based project where i am using the following code

i am using google api 8 for the project

```
 lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    currloc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    try{
        t.setText("Your current location is - "+currloc.getLatitude()+","+currloc.getLongitude());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        t.setText("cant find current location ");
    }
```

this code works fine on my galaxy tab even on htc

but when i use nexus it returns null value for location.
do i need to change my api level or is there any specific requirement for galaxy nexus
thank you in advance :)

Comment: make sure that you have at least one location in history. maybe you don't have enabled your location from your lat boot.

Comment: lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this); here you are passing last param (context of same class), here you should pass instance of listener class.

Comment: follow my below code. i pasted.

Comment: hi vishesh problem is not with code i have implemented locationListener and methods it is for perticular nexus device only

Comment: @Mahesh do you really want the last known location from GPS? Try to get it from other providers as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the line of code..

```
Step1: into your oncreate

LocationListener locationListener = new LocalLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

Step2: into class body

/**Listener on location change*/
private class LocalLocationListener implements LocationListener
{

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        String text = "My current Location is: "+location.getLatitude()+", "+location.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude()* 1E6), (int)(location.getLatitude() * 1E6));
        mapController_.animateTo(geoPoint);
        Toast.makeText(LocalMap.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("onLocationChanged", text);

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(LocalMap.this, "GPS Disable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("onProviderDisabled", "GPS Disable");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(LocalMap.this, "GPS Enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("onProviderEnabled", "GPS Enable");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work.. if I use the `bestProvider` it always returns `null`, but if I use pas...