# Loocationmanager.getLastKnownLocation returns null

Tags: android, location

```
 String serviceString = Context.LocationService;
 lm = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(serviceString);
bestProvider = lm.GetBestProvider(cr, true);
 Location l = lm.GetLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
```

l shows null value where the best provider is network

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: On a device? Emulator? Give us a bit more details please

Comment: getlastknownlocation returns null value..how do i make it store the previous value

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the location via telnet if you use an emulator.. maybe thats why it shows null values...

see also this post [click me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279647/how-to-emulate-gps-location-in-the-android-emulator)

Comment: I dont have problem with emulator,but i've problem working it on my device

Comment: have you add the permissions in the manifest file?
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />`

Comment: Also i found similar questions with yours..check them out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702848/getlastknownlocations-always-returns-null?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681369/getlastknownlocation-returns-null-value-on-nexus?rq=1

the last known location is only available if the location has been determined by another app prior to your call. start maps or some other app and let it get a location lock. then run your app.

Comment: Hey! i got the answer! i dont think we require to add mock_location. we just need to start gps or map application for the first time and later my application works